# CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. Even with {% crsf_token %}

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm getting `CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.` after I try signing in, even though I've provided the `{% csrf_token %}` template tag.

**templates/registration/login.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container">
 <div class="card">

    {% if form.errors %}
    <p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
    {% endif %}

    {% if next %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Your account doesn't have access to this page. To proceed,
      please login with an account that has access.</p>
    {% else %}
    <p>Please login to see this page.</p>
    {% endif %}
    {% endif %}

    <form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form|crispy }}
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i> Login</button>
      <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
    </form>

    {# Assumes you setup the password_reset view in your URLconf #}
    <p><a href="{% url 'password_reset' %}">Lost password?</a></p>
</div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: depending on your `view` just delete `action="{% url 'login' %}"` and it should work allright

Comment: @quqa123 I don't have a login view. I just added `path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))` and that `login.html` template I have above. It worked locally.